# Provisioning profiles and xcode builds

Tags: iphone, ios, adhoc, provisioning-profile

I'm planning to distribute an application ad hoc for beta testing. I have created a provisioning profile for the distribution but it doesn't contain all the devices.

My question is if I need to rebuild the application in XCode if add more devices to the provisioning profile?
Or could I build the app once with the original provisioning profile and when more devices turn up just update and download the new profile file to distribute with the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this in the past, and no-one has complained of an adhoc app not working.

It seems that iTunes checks the provisioning profile's ID against the one signed into the app, and if they match, then it's a green light. It doesn't appear to check whether or not the provisioning profiles are actually identical.

So you should be able to build with the current provisioning profile, and then when new devices are added, send them the app bundled with the new provisioning profile.